# White Screen of Death, From Apache to Litespeed

Tags: migrations, wsod

I'm facing a White Screen of Death on some backend(admin) pages after migrating to a new server. Apache--->LiteSpeed. New domain. When I migrate to a different server running Apache I don't have any issues.

I get WSOD when I click "Flush all caches" or after enabling a module.

The link to configure AWS for PHP module is missing from the admin menu.

**Recent logs messages:**

- page not found   2013-08-01 18:19    build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js
- page not found   2013-08-01 18:20    favicon.ico

May you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to increase your memory_limit and max_execution_time in your php.ini file.

Here is a [link](https://drupal.org/node/31819) that tells you more about that

Comment: you just made my day and thank you, you always come through with great solutions.